# The eruption of Eyjafjallajökull?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Year of 2010, an Icelandic Vulcano, concisely named [Eyjafjallajökull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Is-Eyjafjallaj%C3%B6kull_(3).oga)  erupted, resulting in my long-planned flight being canceled.

In case this ever happens again, I would really like to know in advance, so please help me build a simple visual alert system !

**Input**

Take the [Icelandic Meteorological Office](http://en.vedur.is/earthquakes-and-volcanism/volcanic-eruptions/) volcanic activity alert code, as an input (string):

*GREEN* - Volcano is in normal, non-eruptive state.

*YELLOW* - Volcano is experiencing signs of elevated unrest above known background levels.

*ORANGE* - Volcano is exhibiting heightened unrest with increased likelihood of eruption.

*RED* - Eruption is forecasted to be imminent with significant emission of ash into the atmosphere likely.

**Output**

The graphic (ASCII art) alert, illustrating the state of Eyjafjallajökull.

*GREEN* (Eyjafjallajökull is resting)

```
      al   la 
     j       j
  jaf         öku
 y               l
E                 l
-------------------
```

*YELLOW* (some smoke appears !)

```
       ~   ~
         ~
      al   la 
     j       j
  jaf         öku
 y               l
E                 l
-------------------
```

*ORANGE* (more smoke !)

```
      ~  ~  ~
       ~   ~
         ~
      al   la 
     j       j
  jaf         öku
 y               l
E                 l
-------------------
```

*RED* (even more smoke and some ash, too !)

```
   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
    ` ~  ~  ~ ` 
     ` ~   ~ ` 
       ` ~ `  
      al   la 
     j       j
  jaf         öku
 y               l
E                 l
-------------------
```

**Rules**

- You may output to the screen (stdout), or return a string
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) ! The shortest answer (in bytes), wins
- Feel free to replace **ö** with **o**
- Trailing spaces are allowed, but not required
- At most one trailing newline is allowed
- At most 4 leading newlines are allowed (in place of smoke)

Comment: Pronounced: `AY-JAH-FUH-JUH-AH-LAH-JUh-KUh-EW-LUH`?

Comment: @carusocomputing - Almost it ! :)

Comment: at least it's shorter than _Tungnafellsjökull_ :P

Comment: @DrMcMoylex
No, just a typo, should be fixed now. Thanks !

Comment: You joke about the name not being concise but it's actually very descriptive and shorter than its English translation "island mountain glacier" and also sounds a lot more beautiful. :P

Comment: Are trailing spaces required?

Comment: @darrylyeo, spaces are allowed but not required (updated the rules to mention that).

Comment: Are leading/trailing newlines allowed?

Comment: @Titus - one trailing newline is ok (just added this to the list of rules)

Comment: I've also added a rule allowing for leading newlines (at most 4 of them).
Never intended to do so, but existing answers do rely on this already, so it would be unfair to do otherwise.

Comment: I was expecting the `Eyjafjallajökullmögöröv complexity` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Ruby, 161

Here's my take on Iceland's famous landmark, the Eyjafjallajökull Tower.

Reasonably short but I haven't come up with a good way to golf the smoke yet.

```
->n{m=85-n[-3].ord>>2
%w{`~+~+~+~+~+~` `+~++~++~+` `+~+++~+` `+~+` al%3sla j%7sj jaf%9soku y%15sl E%17sl}.map{|i|(i%"").tr(?++?`*m," ").center(19)}[m,9]+[?-*19]}
```

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
f=->n{m=85-n[-3].ord>>2     #From ASCII code of 3rd from last letter, derive m=0 for RED up to 4 for GREEN (uppercase.)
  %w{`~+~+~+~+~+~` `+~++~++~+` `+~+++~+` `+~+` al%3sla j%7sj jaf%9soku y%15sl E%17sl}.
  map{|i|                   #For each line above decode as follows:
    (i%"").                 #Replace %Xs with X spaces, by inserting  empty strings and padding sprintf style. 
    tr(?++?`*m," ").        #Replace + with space. If not red, replace ` with space.
    center(19)}[m,9]+       #Centre output to 19 characters per line. Start printing at line m and go on to the end (never more than 9 lines.)
  [?-*19]                   #Add a row of --- at the bottom.
}

puts f[gets.chomp]
```

Answer (score 6):

### Batch, 284 bytes

```
@set e=echo 
@%e%off
set s=      
set t=   
goto %1
:RED
set t= ` 
%e%   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`
:ORANGE
%e%   %t%~  ~  ~%t%
:YELLOW
%e%    %t%~   ~%t%
%e%%s%%t%~%t%
:GREEN
%e%%s%al   la 
%e%     j%s% j
%e%  jaf %s%  oku
%e% y %s%%s%  l
%e%E%s%%s%%s%l
%e%--------------------
```

Note: Lines 1 and 7 have one trailing space, line 3 has six and line 4 has three.

Comment: Nice use of `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>286</s> <s>262</s> <s>199</s> <s>194</s> 183 bytes

Pass input to the function `f()`, e.g. `f('GREEN')`.

```js
Y=`7~3~
9~
`
f=n=>({G:'',Y,O:`5 ~2~2~
`+Y,R:'3`~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`\n4` ~2~2~ `\n5` ~3~ `\n7` ~ `\n'}[n[0]]+`6al3la
5j7j
2jaf9oku
 y15l
E17l
`+'-'.repeat(19)).replace(/\d+/g,n=>' '.repeat(n))
```

*-63 bytes: Used Regex instead of function to generate spaces.*

Comment: Is `s` really worth it? By my count, it saves 4 bytes... but costs 16 bytes. On the other hand, I think you could save a couple of bytes by using `_` more.

Comment: Produces invalid results for ORANGE (smoke is not aligned correctly)

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I anticipated that I'd need it more often than I really did. :P

Comment: @zeppelin Fixed.

Comment: it now fails with "r is not defined" for me :(

Comment: I realized that right after I updated! Try it again.

Comment: @darrylyeo It works now !

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>235</s> <s>220</s> 218 bytes

```js
c=>[344,592,160,640,192,32,28,2,1,~0].map(n=>(s='6222222661116600660').replace(/./g,(_,i)=>n&(1<<i|512>>i-9)?(s+'6allajjjafökuylEl')[p++]||'-':' '),p=0).join`
`.replace(/\d/g,n=>n%4<'GYOR'.search(c[0])?n&4?'`':'~':' ')
```

```js
let f =

c=>[344,592,160,640,192,32,28,2,1,~0].map(n=>(s='6222222661116600660').replace(/./g,(_,i)=>n&(1<<i|512>>i-9)?(s+'6allajjjafökuylEl')[p++]||'-':' '),p=0).join`
`.replace(/\d/g,n=>n%4<'GYOR'.search(c[0])?n&4?'`':'~':' ')

console.log(f('GREEN'))
console.log(f('YELLOW'))
console.log(f('ORANGE'))
console.log(f('RED'))
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>307</s> <s>288</s> 279 bytes

```
$o=" ";while($x<19)$o[$x+19*(($d=abs($x-9))>4?$d>7?$d-5:2:$d>3)]="Eyjafjal   lajokull"[$x++];echo strtr((($n=ord($argv[1])/8&3)-2?"":"   1~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~2\n").($n%3?"     1~  ~  ~2\n":"").($n?"      1~   ~2\n       1 ~ 2\n":"").chunk_split(str_pad($o,114,"-"),19),12,$n-2?"  ":"`´");
```

uglyly bulky

**breakdown**

```
$o=" ";                                         // 0.init $o to string
while($x<19)$o[$x+19*(                      // 1.paint volcano
    ($d=abs($x-9))>4?$d>7?$d-5:2:$d>3           // 1a map [0..19] to row offsets
    )]="Eyjafjal   lajokull"[$x++];
echo strtr(                                     // 7. print
    (($n=ord($argv[1])/8&3)                     // 4.map GYOR to 0312
        -2?"":"   1~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~2\n")             // 5a.add smoke & stuff for red
        .($n%3?"     1~  ~  ~2\n":"")           // 5b for orange
        .($n?"      1~   ~2\n       1 ~ 2\n":"")// 5c for yellow
    .chunk_split(                               // 3.insert linebreaks
        str_pad($o,114,"-")                     // 2.add ground
    ,19)
,12,$n-2?"  ":"`´");        // 6.replace stuff with ticks for red, with blanks else
```

Answer (score 1):

## ><> (Fish) <s>351</s> <s>339</s> 302 bytes

```
\l?!;o00.>~00.
\a"-------------------"a"l                 E"a"l               y "a"ukö         faj  "a"j       j     "a" al   la      "
\i:"R"-?!v
 " `  "a~<|.!00"   `~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~`"a"    ` ~  ~  ~ ` "a"     ` ~   ~ ` "a"       ` ~"
\ :"G"-?!v
\}a"~         "a"~   ~       "
\{:"Y"-?!v
\~a"~  ~  ~      "
```

Fairly basic and ugly at the moment, I'm working on golfing it down lower but the 'RED' input makes it harder to re-use lines.

Edit 1; Moved the initial volcano string onto 1 line to reduce line breaks, moved the 'RED' string in reverse to fill empty space. (12 bytes saved)

Edit 2;Took out 'O' check and just print if the other 3 are not inputted (it doesn't specify any non 'green,red,orange,yellow' inputs. Also took out movement and used spaces in the strings to bypass extra commands. (37 bytes saved)

[Online version to test!](https://fishlanguage.com/playground/3wt8ecrY8ZYqFf4Pp)

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2, 209 bytes (208 chars)

```python
s=' '
y=' ~ '
v='ROY G'.index(input()[0])
a='` '[v>0]
print'\n'.join([s*3+a+'~'+' ~'*5+a,s*4+a+y*3+a,s*5+a+y*2+a,s*7+a+y+a,s*6+'al   la ',s*5+'j       j\n  jaf'+s*9+'öku\n y'+s*15+'l\nE'+s*17+'l','-'*19][v:])
```